# How to code a script that could scan the link in my website and produce a thumbnail of that; just like Facebook does

Tags: javascript, php, html

How do I code a script that could scan the links submitted by users in my website and produce a thumbnail of that; just like Facebook does?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a crawler-like script that just goes to that website and parses its contents.

**One way to do it:**

As you may know, Facebook uses Meta tags to help crawlers to find page content more efficiently. You can do the same.

So in a nutshell you may do parsing in these steps.

For simplicity just imagine that our page is test.com.

1. Firstly, you parse the test.com header and search for meta tags that you have predefined and other website creators are using.
2. If there is information, parse that and use the parsed information.
3. If there are no meta tags provided, parse the rest of the page and look for data that suites your needs, like images with pretty good resolution for thumbnail, description meta tags, title, etc.
4. Cache information for further usage to avoid high memory usage.

*Tip: Cache data for relatively short period of time.*

Answer (score -1):

You want a headless browser such as [PhantomJS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhantomJS), which you can script to take screenshots.